# Angular 5 & Jasmine - How to mock activeRoute.firstChild to test unsubscribe on ngOnDestroy

Tags: angular, unit-testing

In my Angular component I create two observables using the following code

```
this.navigationEnd = this.router.events.subscribe((event: any) => {
  // do some stuff
});

if (this.activeRoute.firstChild) {
  this.activeRouteChild = this.activeRoute.firstChild.params.subscribe((routeParams) => {
    // do some stuff
  });
}
```

As you can see I subscribe to the activeRoute and router.events. As I am a good programmer I make sure to unsubscribe from both when the component is destroyed using `ngOnDestroy`

```
public ngOnDestroy(): void {
  if (this.navigationEnd) {
    this.navigationEnd.unsubscribe();
  }
  if (this.activeRouteChild) {
    this.activeRouteChild.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Now this is great but it is time to test that both items are unsubscribe when destroying the component, this is the test I have

```
describe('ngOnDestroy', () => {
  it('should unsubscribe from navigationEnd & activeRouteChild on ngOnDestroy', () => {
    // arrange

    fixture.detectChanges();

    // act
    instance.ngOnDestroy();

    // assert
    expect((instance as any).navigationEnd.closed).toBeTruthy();
    expect((instance as any).activeRouteChild.closed).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I mock both the Router and ActivatedRoute like so:

```
class MockRouter {
  // Router
  public events = of(new NavigationEnd(1, 'url/1', 'url/1'));
  public navigate = () => true;
}

class MockActivatedRoute {
  public firstChild = {params: of({id: '1'})};
}
```

and this is how I declare them in the providers array:

```
{provide: Router, useClass: MockRouter },
{provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: MockActivatedRoute}
```

The Mock Router works great however their is a problem with the MockActivatedRoute as I think I am implementing the `firstChild` property incorrectly. I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'closed' of undefined" - my question is how do I correctly mock the ActivatedRoute and it's firstChild property?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a class to mock the child route, just navigate there in your test by calling navigate with your necessary params. you can verify it by testing that your app doesn't route at first (check that your route path is the initial route) then by checking if the route changed after you navigate (check that your path is what you navigated to). then, you can check if your component unsubscribed after that.

**note**: as far as testing goes, I have found it's not often useful to test API's you didn't write, unless you are contributing to them. unsubscribe() works, and we know that because the contributers to Angular have written tests for  it. Testing it yourself, while not bad, proves often a waste of time because it has already been tested in the Angular source code.